# deallocation of the arrays in implementation cpp C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

It seems so weird...Not sure what cause the Microsoft C++ put red lines under the ~ReadData part of the code. Is there some special I should do when I try to deallocate the int arrays and double array?? Thanks in advance

```
#include "ReadData.h"


ReadData::ReadData(string file)
{
    }

tuple <int *, int *, double *> ReadData::CreatePtr (string file)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(file);
    inFile >> IRP_Length >> CIndx_Length >>A_Length;

    int *IRP=new int[IRP_Length];
    int *CIndx=new int[CIndx_Length];
    double *A=new double[A_Length];

    for (int a = 0; a < IRP_Length; a++)

        inFile >> IRP[a] ;

    for (int b = 0; b < CIndx_Length; b++)

        inFile >> CIndx[b] ;

    for (int c = 0; c < A_Length; c++)

        inFile >> A[c] ;

    inFile.close();
    return   make_tuple(IRP,CIndx,A) ;
}

ReadData::~ReadData()
{
    delete[] IRP;//red line under IRP
    delete[] CIndx;//red line under CIndx
    delete[] A;//red line under A
}
```

Comment: Intellisense it not always correct.

Comment: What are the types of IRP, CIndx, and A?

Comment: please post your header file too

Comment: What is `tuple`? Is the method `CreatePtr()` the template or `tuple`? Maybe you should write `template <> tuple ReadData::CreatePtr<int*,int*,double*> (string file)`? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *IRP=new int[IRP_Length];
int *CIndx=new int[CIndx_Length];
double *A=new double[A_Length];
```

In this lines, you are creating local variables `IRP`, `CIndx`, and `A` and initialising them. It seems to me that you probably have some members with those names that you are meaning to assign to:

```
IRP=new int[IRP_Length];
CIndx=new int[CIndx_Length];
A=new double[A_Length];
```

Intellisense is moaning because you are trying to use these currently uninitialised members.

Comment: I'm betting they aren't declared at all as members and Intellisense is moaning about the undeclared identifiers.

Comment: @FredLarson You may be right. Is a red underline an error?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not a VisualStudio user.

Answer (score 2):

These definitions in function CreatePtr

```
int *IRP=new int[IRP_Length];
int *CIndx=new int[CIndx_Length];
double *A=new double[A_Length];
```

are definitions of local variables. They are not data members of the class.

So in the destructor the compiler sees that you are trying to delete uninitialized data members

```
delete[] IRP;//red line under IRP
delete[] CIndx;//red line under CIndx
delete[] A;//red line under A
```

I think you meant not local variables in function CreatePtr but data members.